# Get Session in Entity in Symfony 2.3

Tags: forms, symfony-2.3

I have problem in retrieving amount from database which is stored in encrypted format.So form defined is showing amount in encrypted format. So I wanted to decrypt amount using key in session in entity class where get method exists

```
 public function getAmount()
    {
        $amount= $this->amount;
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $session=$this->container->getParameter('session');
//get key from session and 
        $rsa_object = new RSA();
            $rsa_object->loadKey($session_pr_key);

                if($amount!=null){


                    $base2Amount=hex2bin($amount);
                    $base10Amount=$rsa_object->decrypt($base2Amount);
                }else{
                    $base10Amount=$base16Amount;
                }
                return $amount;
    }
```

But I'm unable to get session. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. Your entity should just define the class without knowing anything about the container and the session. An entity is a Plain Old PHP Object (POPO). You should have a service or a decrypt object to which pass your entity and the session (or the needed value) and return what you're trying to do in your getAmount.

Comment: Yep, why not. It allows you to move that problem out of the entity.